# In codeigniter which file execute very first before website load?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi friends in an interview i was asked a question which is in codeigniter which file execute very first before the website load. So please let me the answer with working flow of codeigniter. Looking forward for your response. Thanks

Comment: CI is a php framework, php is serverside script. it gets executed when you request a page, first to load in CI is the root index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not changed anything in the framework folder layout, you should have something like

- index.php
- application [folder]
- system [folder]

The very first file executed will be index.php which will set up the framework objects and fire all the system.